# Excel macro to copy values from certain cells and paste them into next empty cells

Tags: vba, excel, copy, paste

I would like to make a quite simple macro which will copy values from certain cells (A1,A5,A9 in my case) and paste them into next empty cells in the same row
like B1,B5,B9. Each run should create a next cell with copied values (not overwriting B1,B5,B9 but putting them into C1,C5,C9 and so on)

Here's my previous code i've managed

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()



'Use the Range.Copy method for a simple copy/paste

    'The Range.Copy Method - Copy & Paste with 1 line
    Range("A1").Copy Range("B1")
    Range("A5").Copy Range("B5")
    Range("A9").Copy Range("B9")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would copy A1,A5,A9 to the **next** empty cell in the same row

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 9 Step 4 'loops 1, 5, 9 because of Step 4
    With Range("A" & i)
        If .Offset(0, 1) = vbNullString Then 'if B is empty
            .Copy .Offset(0, 1)
        Else 'find next free cell
            .Copy .End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1)
        End If
    End With
Next i
```

Alternatively to copy to the cell after **last**  used cell in the same row

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 9 Step 4 'loops 1, 5, 9 because of Step 4
    With Range("A" & i)
        .Copy .Parent.Cells(i, .Parent.Cells.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1)
    End With
Next i
```

---

Note that I strongly recommend to specify in which worksheet the range A1 is (for both variants):
instead of

```
Range("A" & i)
```

always specify a worksheet like

```
Worksheets("SheetName").Range("A" & i)
```

Comment: Thank you very much,that's exactly what i was looking for :D

Comment: @Matt If column B is empty the previous code would fail. See my updated code. Which also uses a loop. If this solved your issue please mark this answer as solution.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use late binding:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("A1").Copy .Cells(1, .Cells(1, .Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1)
    .Range("A5").Copy .Cells(5, .Cells(5, .Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1)
    .Range("A9").Copy .Cells(9, .Cells(9, .Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1)
End With
```